# Активировать iframe по нажатию.

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Допустим есть [код](http://irk-club.esy.es/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0/code)

Надо чтобы iframe не грузился со всей страницей, а по нажатию на него загружался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать "фейковый" элемент, который разместить в родительском элементе iframe-а и отслеживать клик по нему. Пример [тестируем тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/uewxxgp3/1/)

```
var iframe = $('.iframe iframe')
$('<div />').prependTo('.iframe').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    width: iframe.width(),
    height: iframe.height(),
    zIndex: 10
}).on('click', function(){
    $(this).remove();
    iframe.attr('src', 'http://hashcode.ru');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все как надо)

Comment: @ananas_and we are..., не нужно нажимать "наградить" (*когда ж эту кнопку уже уберут?*), достаточно нажать "палец вверх" рядом с вопросом или "галку", если ответ полностью устраивает.